# Linq Error: Average could not be translated

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
        public List<Stats> subjects = _context.Gradebooks
            .Include(s => s.Student)
            .Include(s=>s.Subject)
            .Where(s => s.LessonDate >= startDate && s.LessonDate <= endDate && s.Student.GradeId == gradeId && s.Mark !="0")
            .GroupBy(s=>s.Subject.Name)
            .Select(g=> new Stats
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Avg = g.Average(s=>int.Parse(s.Mark)) //error
                //Avg = g.Average(s => s.StudentId) //works
            }).ToList();
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> 'GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: s.Name,
> ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Gradebook
> ValueBufferExpression: ProjectionBindingExpression:
> EmptyProjectionMember IsNullable: False
>
> .Average(s => int.Parse(s.Mark))' could not be translated. Either
> rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to
> client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

I'm building an asp.net website with Entity Framework Core. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this linq query? I'm getting error about Average function. When I try other stupid value for Average function like StudentId, everything  works. Should I make my nvarchar field in database to int if everything fails?

My entities:
Gradebook
Id int
LessonDate datetime2(7)
Mark nvarchar(20)
StudentId int
SubjectId int
TeacherId int

Subject
Id int
Name nvarchar (50)

Student
GradeId int
(other non relevant properties)

Stats class:

```
    public class Stats
    {
        public string Name;
        public double Avg;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Covert.ToInt32()` instead of `int.Parse()`? Maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: Cannot use Covert.ToInt32 in Linq to entities.

Comment: Why you cannot use `Convert.ToInt32` in LINQ to Entities? Just checked EF Core sources and they have translation to SQL for this function.

Comment: Thank you Random12b3. I don't know how to mark your comment as the right answer. Actually you can use Covert.ToInt32() in linq to entities. Thank you Svyatoslav Danyliv too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Covert.ToInt32() instead of int.Parse() gets rid of the error. Thank you Random12b3 and Svyatoslav Danyliv.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is only possible if you move the ToList() call before the Select call. The reason for this is because you are trying to convert mark from string to an int before it is actually retrieved from the DB. The following code will most probably work:

```cs
public List<Stats> subjects = _context.Gradebooks
    .Include(s => s.Student)
    .Include(s => s.Subject)
    .Where(s => s.LessonDate >= startDate && s.LessonDate <= endDate && s.Student.GradeId == gradeId && s.Mark !="0")
    .GroupBy(s => s.Subject.Name)
    .ToList()
    .Select(g => new Stats
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Avg = g.Average(s => int.Parse(s.Mark))
    });
```

Comment: It's giving me this error: InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.

Comment: Instead of the ToList() try using AsEnumerable()